# How to advertise Bluetooth using electron on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, bluetooth, electron, bluetooth-gatt

I am aware of Web Bluetooth APIs being accessible in electron. The limitation right now is that those APIs can only be used to connect to nearby devices, but not advertise the device itself.

Are there any options for advertising the existance of the Mac OS app?

Currently researching for ways to use some CLI tool, calling Swift from electron, or interacting somehow with bluetooth via node.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Nope. If I were to had a go at this now I would have a look at JNI solutions, or other libraries that wrap Native APIs for you such as rococoa. not much time to do that now

Comment: I had some success long time ago when I needed electron to connect to Bluetooth devices. I tested on Mac, Windows and Linux. I used a bluetooth nodejs module called noble (https://github.com/noble/noble). In that repo, it is mention that there is another module called bleno (https://github.com/noble/bleno). Bleno is for peripheral side part, where it enables the application to advertise bluetooth. But I have not tried this module and I'm not sure if it will work. Maybe it is something worth checking out because I was very satisfied with it's counterpart module noble few years ago.